# Trying to get average rating from multiple rating json data need help to improve performance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

My this code giving correct rating

```
let totalReviewCount = updatedReviewData.length;
let totalSchoolRating = 0;
let totalAccomodationRating = 0;

for (const item of updatedReviewData) {
  totalSchoolRating += item.avgSchoolRating;
  totalAccomodationRating += item.avgAccomodationRating;
}
const avgSchoolRating = totalSchoolRating / totalReviewCount;
const avgAccomodationRating = totalAccomodationRating / totalReviewCount;
const avgRating = (avgSchoolRating + avgAccomodationRating) / 2; // Calculate the overall average rating
```

but here some performance issue like i am doing for loop to calculate full data
how can I improve it?

here data sample json

```
[
  {
    "review_date": "2023-09-05",
    "avgUserRating": 3.5,
    "avgSchoolRating": 3,
    "id": "e98c53fb-e272-4ca2-9f48-2a7930ecdaec",
    "accomodation_evaluation": {
      "accomodation_cleanliness_evaluation": 4,
      "accomodation_equipment_evaluation": 4,
      "accomodation_improvementContent": "test",
      "accomodation_otherContent": "test",
      "accomodation_reviewContent": "test",
      "accomodation_size_evaluation": 4
    },
    "avgAccomodationRating": 4,
    "school_evaluation": {
      "activity_evaluation": 3,
      "equipment_evaluation": 3,
      "improvementContent": "test",
      "instructor_evaluation": 3,
      "location_evaluation": 3,
      "otherContent": "test",
      "reviewContent": "test",
      "support_evaluation": 3
    },
    "school_id": "64a77e25-33a7-43c3-8221-259f6b5cc7e9"
  },
  {
    "review_date": "2023-09-05",
    "avgUserRating": 3.5,
    "avgSchoolRating": 3,
    "id": "e98c53fb-e272-4ca2-9f48-2a7930ecdaec",
    "accomodation_evaluation": {
      "accomodation_cleanliness_evaluation": 4,
      "accomodation_equipment_evaluation": 4,
      "accomodation_improvementContent": "test",
      "accomodation_otherContent": "test",
      "accomodation_reviewContent": "test",
      "accomodation_size_evaluation": 4
    },
    "avgAccomodationRating": 4,
    "school_evaluation": {
      "activity_evaluation": 3,
      "equipment_evaluation": 3,
      "improvementContent": "test",
      "instructor_evaluation": 3,
      "location_evaluation": 3,
      "otherContent": "test",
      "reviewContent": "test",
      "support_evaluation": 3
    },
    "school_id": "64a77e25-33a7-43c3-8221-259f6b5cc7e9"
  }
]
```

Comment: I don't see a problem with the performance of the code you have provided. In order to calculate a sum (total), you must access every item as you are doing. 

The only way I could see to improve performance would be to parallelize the calculation by chunking up the list into multiple lists, performing the same loop-based calculation on each chunk, and then merging the results.

Comment: @ljhennessy if i have 1000 item in json how can I chunk them and calculate total? can you please suggest me some example?